# Merging two data tables with missing values using bash

Tags: bash, text, merge

I'm looking for a script that can merge two files containing tables.
The columns are bacterial counts for individual samples, while the rows contain names of bacteria. I can't just sort and merge them, because some bacteria only occur in one file but not the other. If this is the case, I would like to fill the row with zeros.

Here is an example:

File 1

```
Header                         S1    S2    S3    S4
Acetobacterium submarinus     1350  1000   1541 1541
Abiotrophia defectiva         100   110    112  166
Acetobacterium tundrae         2     1      0     0
```

File 2

```
Header                         S5    S6     S7    S8
Acholeplasma cavigenitalium   100    90    88    120
Acetobacterium woodii          2     3      4     0
Acetobacterium submarinus     500   600    400   480
```

And the resulting file should be (sorted alphabetically)

```
Header                         S1    S2    S3    S4    S5    S6     S7    S8
Abiotrophia defectiva         100   110    112  166     0     0     0      0
Acetobacterium submarinus     1350  1000   1541  1541  500   600    400   480
Acetobacterium tundrae         2     1      0     0     0     0      0     0
Acetobacterium woodii          0     0      0     0     2     3      4     0
Acholeplasma cavigenitalium    0     0      0     0    100    90    88    120
```

Any ideas?

I know the paste function can merge files by the first column, but I'm not sure how to deal with the missing species.

Update
Here are two sample data sets. The column number is the same as in the original dataset, I just shortened the number of rows.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/h46nwjwwfdyzwqr/Class_Level_Aggregate_Counts-1.csv?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/x8wtdxl45bej729/Class_Level_Aggregate_Counts-2.csv?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `join` with the `-a 1 2`, `-e '0'` and `-o '0,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5'` options:

```
join -a 1 -a 2 -e '0' -1 1 -2 1 -o '0,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5' -t $'\t' file1 file2 > joinedfile
```

Since `join` needs sorted input, and you want Header line to be on the top, you have to exclude this first line and then sort:

```
sed -n '2,$p' file1unsorted | sort >file1
sed -n '2,$p' file2unsorted | sort >file2
```

After that, run the above `join` command for the sorted files (notice also the `-t` that specifies column delimiter - I assume you have `Tab`-separated file).

Join you header separately:

```
head -1 file1unsorted | join -1 1 -2 1 -o '0,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5' -t $'\t' - <(head -1 file2unsorted) >headerfile
```

And then "reassemble" your final file (add new header to the rest of the file):

```
cat headerfile joinedfile >resulfile
```

Update:

As to the dependence of `join` on the number of columns (in case your files have more columns): yes, there is a dependence, to some degree. To be precise, the column numbers are used in the `-1` and `-2` options (the value for both is `1` which is the number of the column in the respective file that you are joining on; obviously it doesn't depend on the total number of columns as long as you are joining on the first column). Column numbers are also used in the `-o` option that specifies output format (i.e. which columns and in which order are to be output, the format being "file#.column#", both starting from 1, and the column used for join has the special syntax of "0"). The format we specified in our example is actually the default one (first goes the column to join on, then all the rest of the columns from the 1st file, followed by all other columns of the 2nd file), but unfortunately we still cannot omit this option since `-e` option requires it (it might not in your version of `join`, so try omitting `-o` part and see what happens).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67279/discussion-on-answer-by-striving-coder-merging-two-data-tables-with-missing-valu).

Comment: @bluefeet: I tried, but OP didn't have enough rep to talk in the chat.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the old-fashion **brute force method** works where it is difficult to shoehorn your data into a single function. The following Bash script reads the two datafiles, manipulates them incrementally into tmp files (in /tmp) sorted, then reads the values into arrays, and finally for each unique name, combines the `S1 - S8` values if the data is present in both files, otherwise it fills in missing values with `0`s. A `trap` function removes the temp files on exit. The file is well commented to help explain the logic. **Note** this is a Bash solution (due primarily to the substing test operator), but could be adapted easily to other shell environments. Let me know if you have questions:

```
#!/bin/bash

## simple error/usage function
function usage {
    errno=${2:-0}
    if test -n "$1" ; then
        printf "\n %s\n" "$1"
    fi
cat >&2 <<TAG

  Merge two bacterial count data files zeroing non-common columns.

  Usage:  ./${0//*\//} file_1 file_2

TAG
    exit $((errno))
}

## semi-random tmp file timestamp 'mmdd????'
function tstamp {
    local rd=$(date +%N)
    printf "%s" "$(date +%m%d)${rd:4:4}"
}

## trap function - cleanup temp files
function cleanup {
    rm "$tfn1"
    rm "$tfn2"
    rm "$tfnall"
    rm "$tfnuniq"
}

## respond to help
test "$1" = "-h" -o "$1" = "--help" && usage

## validate input files
test -z "$1" && usage "error: insufficient input." 1
test -z "$2" && usage "error: insufficient input." 1
test -r "$1" || usage "error: invalid input, file not readable '$1'" 1
test -r "$2" || usage "error: invalid input, file not readable '$2'" 1

## assign temp file names
tfn1="/tmp/bmrg_$(tstamp).tmp"      # temp file_1 (sorted w/o header)
tfn2="/tmp/bmrg_$(tstamp).tmp"      # temp file_2 (sorted w/o header)
tfnall="/tmp/bmrg_$(tstamp).tmp"    # concatenated $tfn1 $tfn2
tfnuniq="/tmp/bmrg_$(tstamp).tmp"   # uniq records $tfn1 $tfn2

## create $tfn1 $tfn2 & validate
tail -n+2 "$1" | sort > "$tfn1"
tail -n+2 "$2" | sort > "$tfn2"

test -f "$tfn1" || usage "error: failed to create tmp file '${tfn1}'" 1
test -f "$tfn2" || usage "error: failed to create tmp file '${tfn2}'" 1

## set trap for cleanup on exit
trap cleanup EXIT

## read names from $tfn1
while read -r name || test -n "$name" ; do
    name1+=( "$name" )
done <<<"$(cut -c -30 "$tfn1")"
unset name

## read names from $tfn2
while read -r name || test -n "$name" ; do
    name2+=( "$name" )
done <<<"$(cut -c -30 "$tfn2")"
unset name 

## concatenate $tfn1 $tfn2
printf "%s\n" "${name1[@]}" > "$tfnall"
printf "%s\n" "${name2[@]}" >> "$tfnall"

## get unique names
sort -u "$tfnall" > "$tfnuniq"

## read $tfn1 values into separate arrays
while read -r v1 v2 v3 v4 || test -n "$v4" ; do
    s1+=( "$v1" )
    s2+=( "$v2" )
    s3+=( "$v3" )
    s4+=( "$v4" )
done <<<"$(cut -c 31- "$tfn1")"

## read $tfn2 values into separate arrays
while read -r v5 v6 v7 v8 || test -n "$v8" ; do
    s5+=( "$v5" )
    s6+=( "$v6" )
    s7+=( "$v7" )
    s8+=( "$v8" )
done <<<"$(cut -c 31- "$tfn2")"

printf "Header                         S1    S2    S3    S4    S5    S6    S7    S8\n"

## for each unique name in $tfnuniq
while read -r name || test -n "$name" ; do

    ## test if found in name1, print values by index, else print 0's
    found=0
    for ((i=0; i < ${#name1[@]}; i++)); do
        test "${name1[i]}" = "$name" && { found=1; break; }
    done
    if test "$found" -eq 1 ; then
        printf "%-30s%-6s%-6s%-6s%-6s" "$name" "${s1[i]}" "${s2[i]}" "${s3[i]}" "${s4[i]}"
    else
        printf "%-30s%-6s%-6s%-6s%-6s" "$name" "0" "0" "0" "0"
    fi

    ## test if found in name2, print values by index, else print 0's
    found=0
    for ((i=0; i < ${#name2[@]}; i++)); do
        test "${name2[i]}" = "$name" && { found=1; break; }
    done
    if test "$found" -eq 1 ; then
        printf "%-6s%-6s%-6s%-6s\n" "${s5[i]}" "${s6[i]}" "${s7[i]}" "${s8[i]}"
    else
        printf "%-6s%-6s%-6s%-6s\n" "0" "0" "0" "0"
    fi

done <"$tfnuniq"

exit 0
```

**output:**

```
$ bash bactmerge.sh dat/bact1.txt dat/bact2.txt
Header                         S1    S2    S3    S4    S5    S6    S7    S8
Abiotrophia defectiva         100   110   112   166   0     0     0     0
Acetobacterium submarinus     1350  1000  1541  1541  500   600   400   480
Acetobacterium tundrae        2     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
Acetobacterium woodii         0     0     0     0     2     3     4     0
Acholeplasma cavigenitalium   0     0     0     0     100   90    88    120
```

**Note:** the script relies on the spacing of the data files provided in your question. If your data files are different than posted (e.g. due to tab/space conversion) you can adjust the value provided to the `cut` command above.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried the script; however, in the output I get the same problem as with the other solution. The individual bacteria are duplicated. I.e. there is two rows of each bacteria, and the counts are split between the rows, not by input file, but by some other split. Also, is it possible to read the header from the files? What I gave above is just a short example, the real files contain about 100 columns each, and the sample names are not as simple.

Comment: Oh. That does change things a bit. Your sample files were relatively simple. If you can post a link to an actual data file (or at least 20 lines with full columns), then I can tweak the script. The key will be what the length of the names. As long as that is consistent, then adapting the script to read an unlimited number of values isn't difficult. I thought from your example it was only `S1-S8`. You can confirm if you run it against your sample data -- it works as advertised. There are also a **lot** of bash subtleties included, if you are learning, this is a good one to digest.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that. I will add links to some example data files, but I will need to truncate them a bit.

Comment: Thank you! I will certainly have a closer look at the script and learn as much as I can from it.